# Python | Tkinter проблема

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]

Создал программу для получения файлов через интерфейс tkinter, но появилась проблема, вместе с окном файловой системы появсяется второе пустое окно которое мне не нужно, как от него избавится?

```
code [/...]

from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
def open_file():
    filepath = askopenfilename(
        filetypes=[("All files", "*.*")]
    )
    if not filepath:
        return
    else:
        return filepath
g = open_file()
print(g)
```

Comment: Дублирующий вопрос не про filedialog, а про messagebox, но решение аналогичное.

Comment: Объяснение в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1156530/1365

Comment: @insolor как мне заменить получение файла таким способом?

Comment: Выполнить `root = tk.Tk()` `root.withdraw()` перед вызовом диалога открытия файла.