# Как убрать окно tkinter в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, messagebox

Простой код, выводит сообщение об ошибке. Но при его показе, также выскакивает окно ткинтера.

Как его убрать?

```
from tkinter import messagebox

messagebox.showerror('error title', 'error message')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дубликат: [Почему появляется главное окно при вызове massagebox?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1156512/1365)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.withdraw()

messagebox.showerror(title="error title", message="error message")

window.destroy()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]